# Where can I find which packages are on each Debian Squeeze CD?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, distribution-media

I just installed Debian Squeeze on my E1505.  In order to get my wireless card working, I'm trying to install [network-manager-gnome](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/network-manager-gnome) (I already installed firmware-iwlwifi)

My current question is, how can I figure out which CD this 
(and its dependencies) is on, and in general where is this listed?  There are [52 CDs](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/6.0.1a/i386/iso-cd/).  I realize they're roughly in order of usefulness, but I'd rather not download any blindly.

Comment: More context would be helpful. Do you have a network connection? If so, is there some reason you can't just download the packages you need using `apt` and friends? Downloading the cds in general is not very efficient.

Comment: @Faheem, if I need to, I can run a CAT5 cable and try to get Ethernet working.  However, I can't find my long cable, so this might be inconvenient.

Comment: You may want to consider [apt-zip](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-zip) or [aptoncd](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/aptoncd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer I could find is http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#search-for-package

The following question is also relevant http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#list-image-contents

Maybe you could just download the jigdo files and look at them. They are very small.

```
$ ls -lah debian-6.0.1a-amd64-CD-1.jigdo 
 -rw-r--r-- 1 faheem faheem 31K Mar 22 21:39 debian-6.0.1a-amd64-CD-1.jigdo
```

From [How Jigdo Works](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-Jigdo/howjigdoworks.html), Section 3.3,

> Given an input of an ISO image and a
>   set of loose files which may or may
>   not be in the ISO image, jigdo-file
>   outputs a .jigdo file for that ISO
>   image. The Debian .jigdo files are
>   gzipped, so you need to use zcat or
>   zless to view them. Here's what a
>   .jigdo file looks like when you gunzip
>   it:
>
> ```
>   md5-0=http://somemirror.org/file-0
>   md5-1=http://somemirror.org/file-1
>   md5-2=http://somemirror.org/file-2
>   md5-3=http://somemirror.org/file-3
> ```

Comment: I get a 404 when I try the [linked search](http://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/#search).

Comment: So I see. The search seems to be busted. I'd just download the jigdo files and look at them.

Comment: I shot an email about this to debian-cd@lists.debian.org, just in case anyone else was thinking of doing so.

Comment: I downloaded the jigdo for CD 2, and it's not human-readable.

Comment: @Matthew: It is gzipped. Use zcat or zless.